# "Demo App has Stopped" but code compiles fine?

Tags: java, android, xml

i recently tried adding in a RecycleView to my android app, and since then the Demo app just refuses to open on the emulator, all of the code compiles and i cant find the area in which I've gone wrong, ill post the relevant (I think, because im not sure as to whats wrong) code below, but will also provide a download link to the project in case that is easier to anyone.

I know there's a lot of code but im super stumped as to where this has gone wrong and caused the demo app to not work at all, im fairly certain it lies within the RecycleView but again, im genuinely not sure what so any guidance is greatly appreciated

Download Link https://www.dropbox.com/s/7uott0yaiktieym/JavaMini.zip?dl=0

Image List adapter Class

```
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ImageListAdapter
    extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView mainImage;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
        mainImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
    }
}
public ArrayList<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>();

//context
private Context context;

 public ImageListAdapter(Context context) { this.context = context;}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cell_image_card, 
parent, false);

            ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new 
ImageListAdapter.ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String image = imageList.get(position);

    holder.imageTitle.setText(image);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 5;
}
}
```

MainActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
private ImageListAdapter adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cell_image_card);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.imageList);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    adapter = new ImageListAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/imageList"
        android:layout_width="361dp"
        android:layout_height="484dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: *Compiles* does not mean *does not contain a logical error*; it just means that syntax is correct. Use a debugger and step through the code to see what is actually happening.

Comment: @KenWhite i see, im kind of bad at this, how would i go about setting up a debugger?

Comment: What IDE are you using? If it's Android Studio, then a simple Google search for *Android Studio debugger* turns up a tutorial regarding it's use. Also, have you looked to see if the logcat provides any information that may help? (And for future reference, we don't download your project to see the code. All **relevant** code needs to be here, in the post itself, in the form of a [mcve]. You may want to do as suggested when you created your account here and take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site.)

Comment: Here's a link for you: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html

Comment: POST you error logcat here